# Solution of Functional Equation With Integration

Tags: calculus

Suppose $$f(t)=\int^x_0f(t+y)-f(y)dy$$,for every $x>0$ and all real $t$
$$$$ Prove that $f(t+z)=f(t)$ for every real $t>0$.
$$f(t+z)=\int^x_0f(t+z+y)-f(t+y)+f(t+y)-f(y)dy=\int^x_0f(t+z+y)-f(t+y)dy+\int_0^xf(t+y)-f(y)dy=\int^x_0f(t+z+y)-f(t+y)dy+f(t)$$
Now if we take $t+y=u$ then we get $$f(t+z)=\int_t^{x+t}f(z+u)-f(u)du+f(t)=\int_t^0f(z+u)-f(u)du+\int_0^{x+t}f(u+z)-f(u)du+f(t)=\int_0^{x+t}f(u+z)-f(u)du-\int^t_0f(u+z)-f(u)du+f(t)=f(z)-f(z)+f(t)=f(t)$$ for all $t>0$.
$$$$ So we get $f(t+z)=f(t)$ for all $t>0$
$$$$Is this correct??